# Why is %20 Attached to URL Address localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, url, crud

I'm building a node app with mongo. I'm trying to perform basic CRUD on my app resources i.e mongo. Creating and Reading data work fine but the problem occurs when I try to update or delete data from mongo.

I have used morgan to log all requests and in my console terminal, I see `%20` attached to my resource end point like:

```
GET /admin/routes/delete-page/%205a958ac44d47582a841a0f5c 404 4.641 ms - 191
```

Subsequently my edit and delete requests are failing.

Here's a sample of my delete request code:

```
router.delete('/delete-page/:page_id', (req, res)=>{
   let pageId = req.params.page_id;
   console.log(pageId);

   Pages.findByIdAndRemove({_id: pageId})
       .exec()
       .then(result => {
           if (result){
                console.log(`Page Deleted`);
                req.flash('success', 'Page Deleted');
                res.redirect('/admin/routes');
           } else {
                console.log(`Error Deleting Page`);
           }
       })
       .catch(err => {
          console.log(`Requested Page Not Found`);
          console.error(err);
       });

});
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: "Reading data work fine" - the error message suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET /admin/routes/delete-page/%205a958ac44d47582a841a0f5c
```

`%20` there is a url-encoded space. *Something* is producing a broken link. Most likely candidate is your view (or whereever that url is generated). My second best guess is a proxy of some kind (faulty nginx rule, for example).

Comment: @JosephIbe it's an entirely different question now. Don't do that. Rollback the edit and ask another question.

Comment: Okay. I'll do that. Please respond like you did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`%20` means there is a space in the `url` you are providing. This is failing your request.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Yes, but I'm not attaching any space in my code. How to fix this?

Comment: you may be copying the string. Type the url manually and see if it works.

Comment: Manually getting rid of %20 still fails the request

Comment: `_id: pageId` try to remove the space and pass it like `_id:pageId` and see if it works. this should be handled automatically but a test case.

Comment: Thanks buddy!! I have edited the question, please look again

Comment: @Shahzeb: `like _id:pageId` - no, that space is insignificant

Answer (score 0):

It's the string space encoded in URL format. You can find out more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

In your case you have a space at the beginning of the id. A quick fix is to remove white space from the beginning/end of the id by using [trim](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) or [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) if you want to remove the '%20' and not the space.

You can keep in mind that the space might be added when you initially store the `page_id`, so you better fix the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have edited the question, please look again

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly,

%20 is for blank space that is replace by "%20".

Status 404 is site not found, is the URL correct?

Comment: Line below is this logging correct value. console.log(pageId);